# Can't access to password input on registration form

Tags: users

I have a problem. I can't access through module to password field on registration page.

```
function customization_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
$form['account']['pass']['#id'] = 'userRegInput';
}
```

It wont change id of input. I don't know why...

Thank you!

EDIT: Btw. i have installed user_registrationpassword module, maybe is because of that...

Comment: Hmmm user_registrationpassword should not be a problem here, please let us know if it is, or not. (so we can fix it, or not) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the password form field in the registration form, but the ID you are setting is not used.

When a password_confirm form field is being added to a form, Drupal is really adding two password form field with a process function ([form_process_password_confirm()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_process_password_confirm/7)); that function doesn't use the ID set for the password_confirm field for the new fields.
There isn't a theme function for the password_confirm form field, which means that the following code (executed from theme_password(), and theme functions for other form fields) is not executed.

```
element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'size', 'maxlength'));
_form_set_class($element, array('form-text'));
```

What you can do is to wrap the password_confirm form field with a `<div>` tag to which you assign your ID.

```
$form['account']['pass']['#prefix'] = '<div id="userRegInput">';
$form['account']['pass']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

If you are using the CSS ID to execute JavaScript code, or to style the field, keep in mind that the default output for the password_confirm field (for the form field you are interested) is the following one.

```
<div class="form-item form-type-password-confirm form-item-pass">
  <div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass-pass1 password-parent">
    <div class="password-strength">
      <div class="password-strength-text" aria-live="assertive"></div>
      <div class="password-strength-title">Password strength:</div>
      <div class="password-indicator">
        <div class="indicator"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <label for="edit-pass-pass1">Password <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
    <input class="password-field form-text required password-processed" type="password" id="edit-pass-pass1" name="pass[pass1]" size="25" maxlength="128">
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass-pass2 confirm-parent">
    <div class="password-confirm">Passwords match: <span></span></div>
    <label for="edit-pass-pass2">Confirm password <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
    <input class="password-confirm form-text required" type="password" id="edit-pass-pass2" name="pass[pass2]" size="25" maxlength="128">
  </div>
  <div class="password-suggestions description" style="display: none; "></div>
  <div class="description">Provide a password for the new account in both fields.</div>
</div>
```

The HTML output includes also the output from the JavaScript code that outputs the password strength.

As alternative, you can add a process function that is executed after the process functions normally used by Drupal.

```
$form['account']['pass']['#process'] = array('form_process_password_confirm', 'mymodule_process_password_confirm', 'user_form_process_password_confirm');
```

Use [form_process_password_confirm()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_process_password_confirm/7) as guideline for the code you should write.

```
function form_process_password_confirm($element) {
  $element['pass1'] =  array(
    '#type' => 'password', 
    '#title' => t('Password'), 
    '#value' => empty($element['#value']) ? NULL : $element['#value']['pass1'], 
    '#required' => $element['#required'], 
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('password-field')),
  );
  $element['pass2'] =  array(
    '#type' => 'password', 
    '#title' => t('Confirm password'), 
    '#value' => empty($element['#value']) ? NULL : $element['#value']['pass2'], 
    '#required' => $element['#required'], 
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('password-confirm')),
  );
  $element['#element_validate'] = array('password_confirm_validate');
  $element['#tree'] = TRUE;

  if (isset($element['#size'])) {
    $element['pass1']['#size'] = $element['pass2']['#size'] = $element['#size'];
  }

  return $element;
}
```

[user_form_process_password_confirm()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_form_process_password_confirm/7) just adds the JavaScript code to handle the password strength, and any messages about the used password (e.g. *Make it at least 6 characters*, *Make it different from your username*).

I tried using the following code in my test site, and the output for the password field didn't change.

```
function code_testing_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['account']['pass']['#attributes'] = array('id' => array('userRegInput'));
}
```

The ID is not being added to the form field.

```
<div class="form-item form-type-password-confirm form-item-pass">
  <div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass-pass1 password-parent">
    <div class="password-strength">
      <div class="password-strength-text" aria-live="assertive"></div>
      <div class="password-strength-title">Password strength:</div>
      <div class="password-indicator">
         <div class="indicator"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <label for="edit-pass-pass1">Password <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
    <input class="password-field form-text required password-processed" type="password" id="edit-pass-pass1" name="pass[pass1]" size="25" maxlength="128">
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass-pass2 confirm-parent">
    <div class="password-confirm">Passwords match: <span></span></div>
    <label for="edit-pass-pass2">Confirm password <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
    <input class="password-confirm form-text required" type="password" id="edit-pass-pass2" name="pass[pass2]" size="25" maxlength="128">
  </div>
  <div class="password-suggestions description" style="display: none; "></div>
  <div class="description">Provide a password for the new account in both fields.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$form['account']['pass']['#attributes'] = array('id' => array('userRegInput'));
```

IDs and classes must be passed in as arrays in the ['#attributes' form API property](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes) for a form item.

Note that Drupal automatically adds an ID of `edit-[field_name]` on all form inputs, so you'll be overriding that generated ID. I'd recommend setting a class instead, in most circumstances, unless you have good reason for using an ID.